# get the real path of multi selected PDF

Tags: java, android, android-studio, path, uri

i have this code to multi select PDF from device and i need the real path of each PDF, when i select one PDF i can get the real path using

```
String path = data.getData().getPath();
```

but in case of multi select i can only get the URI of each selected PDF (for my knowledge), here is the code.

```
    private void selectPDFs() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {
                            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                                int cItem = 0;
                                while (cItem < count) {
                                    String uri = Data.getClipData().getItemAt(cItem).getUri().toString();
                                    File f = new File(uri); // here i need the real path instead of uri
                                    files.add(f); // files is an ArrayList<File>
                                    cItem++;
                                }
                            } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                                String path = data.getData().getPath(); // path is the real file path
                                File f = new File(path);
                                files.add(f);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `// path is the real file path` No. It is not. Its a useless value. You dont need a `real' path as you got real uris. You can do all with the uri.

Comment: "i have this code to multi select PDF from device" -- the content that the user chooses is not always going to be on the device.

Answer (score -1):

To get the real path from a content URI, you can use the ContentResolver to query the MediaStore and obtain the file path. Here's an updated version of your onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Intent data = result.getData();
        if (data != null) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                int cItem = 0;
                while (cItem < count) {
                    Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(cItem).getUri();
                    String filePath = getRealPathFromUri(uri);
                    if (filePath != null) {
                        File f = new File(filePath);
                        files.add(f);
                    }
                    cItem++;
                }
            } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                String path = getRealPathFromUri(data.getData());
                if (path != null) {
                    File f = new File(path);
                    files.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    } else {
        return uri.getPath(); // For non-MediaStore URIs, like FileProvider
    }
}
```

This getRealPathFromUri method uses a ContentResolver to query the MediaStore and obtain the real file path from the content URI. If the URI is not a MediaStore URI, it falls back to using the URI's path. This should work for both single and multiple selections.